# Search a string inside a document property of mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to search a string inside object of document in mongoose model. I have a Schema of book and I have a `bookName(String)` in that schema.

Now from client side, I just want to render books with string "Business" in `bookName` for all the entries in Book document. I have tried regex without success.

Comment: share your code and schema.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was not returning the promise properly, so when I figured it out it worked out for me.